dlib 68 facial landmarks can't get face landmark with glasses and beside image
I use dlib "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" to get face landmark on some face with glasses or show only beside or blurred face it give me a blank coordinate. The picture that I use are from the deepfake one so some of it face is incomplete but I really need it to have a landmark. Image example enter image description here enter image description hereenter image description here enter image description here Do you guy have any recommend augmentation or solution? this is my code.
def DLIB(submit_path):
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
    image = cv2.imread(submit_path)
    image2 = cv2.resize(image, (996, 996))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    rects = detector(gray, 0)
    error = False
    if len(rects) == 0:
        error = True
    else:
        for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
            shape = predictor(gray, rect)
            shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
            for (x, y) in shape:
                cv2.circle(image2, center=(x, y), radius=3, color=(0, 0, 225), thickness=6)
    return image2, error

def shape_to_np(shape, dtype="int"):
    coords = np.zeros((68, 2), dtype=dtype)
    for i in range(0, 68):
        coords[i] = (shape.part(i).x, shape.part(i).y)
    return coords

